# Smooth map on a closed subset which does not have an extension

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M, N$ be smooth manifolds s.t. $N$ has no boundary. Let $A\subset M$ be a closed subset. $F:A\rightarrow N$ is called smooth if there is an extension $F':U\rightarrow N$ for some open $U\subset M$.

> But can we always extend a smooth $F$ to the whole $M$ ?

I know that there is a smooth extension iff there is a continuous extension. Also, if $N=\mathbb{R}^k$ then the answer is positive.

Comment: It looks like considering an embedding $i:N\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ solves the issue.. Is that correct?

Comment: Hint: $M={\mathbb R}$, $A=\{0, 1\}=N$, $F$ is the identity map.

Answer (score 1):

Smoothness doesn't actually come into it. As you noted, continuous extension is the main obstruction. There are at least two things to worry about.

1. **Connectedness** (as mentioned by [Moishe Kohan in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3540378/smooth-map-on-a-closed-subset-which-does-not-have-an-extension#comment7281726_3540378)).

   Suppose that $M$ is connected, $A = A_1 \sqcup A_2$ has multiple components, and $N = N_1 \sqcup N_2$ also has multiple components, and $F$ is such that $F(A_1) \subset N_1$ and $F(A_2) \subset N_2$, then there cannot be any continuous extension of $F$ that maps $M \to N$.
2. **Topology**

   Continuous maps induce (for example) homomorphisms of the fundamental groups. This can cause some trouble. For example, let $M = \mathbb{S}^2$ and $N = \mathbb{S}^1$. Let $A$ be the equator and $F$ the obvious mapping. If there were a continuous extension of $F$ to the whole manifold, then since $M$ has vanishing $\pi_1$ the image of every closed curve under $F$ has to be contractible in $N$. However, this is manifestly not the case given our prescription that the equator is mapped into $N$ as a non-contractible loop.

Comment: (It may be worth noting that when $N = \mathbb{R}^k$ it is both connected and has trivial topology, and so both problems can be avoided.)